# C#, Winforms и WebBrowser: почему не обрабатываются стили?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

я пытаюсь "дешево и сердито" сделать splash-screen для своего приложения. (WinForms приложение на NET Framework 4.8)

Идея простая: на время загрузки данных показываем элемент WebBrowser, который Navigate() на какой то заранее подготовленный URL с картинкой "подождите, идёт загрузка!"

Но вот беда.

Эта надпись при загрузке данных - это просто картинка (на самом деле - это анимированный gif, чтобы пользоваель не скучал)

в барузере у меня эта картинка показывается по центру экрана:

а в приложении - нет, она показывается в левом верхнем углу, как будто контрол WebBrowser (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) не понимает стилей.

[image: not in center]

Исходный html для показа в браузере:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="min-height: 100vh;" bgcolor="red">
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100%; min-height: 100vh;">
    <img src="BackgroundLoad.gif">  
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Как я показываю бразуер на форме: я просто обрабатываю событие Shown, и в него прописываю код

```
        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        Controls.Add(wb);
        wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        wb.Navigate(new Uri("https://junecat.ru/Storage/oth/BackgroundLoad.html"));
```

На всякий случай - вот [ссылка](https://git@github.com:junecat/Question1ForSO.git) на проект на github.

У меня как то нет идей, почему WebBrowser себя так ведет. А у Вас?

Comment: `WebBrowser` (MSIE 11) устарел, умер и разложился. Вы точно хотите использовать браузер для этого? Вам браузер нужен только для того чтобы гифку показать чтоли? А так, верстку надо сделать совместимой с Internet Explorer, только и всего (он не поддерживает и никогда не поддерживал `flex`).

Comment: Да, а еще - чтобы gif'ка показывалась в отдельном процессе,  а не в том же основном треде, где я мог бы запустить показ gif в PictureBox, например. Спасибо за ответ, теперь понятно, то надо применить какой то старый способ центирования картинки - при помощи таблиц, например.

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что воспроизведение GIF от вас требует какого-то процесса? Вы правда думаете, что другого способа нет? Вы в курсе, что Microsoft скоро выкинет Trident из операционки, и все ваши старания будут только для устаревших версий винды? Вы вообще в курсе, что браузер жрет немеряно ресурсов и стартует гораздо медленнее, чем ваше приложение? А еще загрузить гифку с инета надо успеть (полмегабайта в вашем случае). Сплеш скрин загрузки для сплеш скрина загрузки будете как делать?

Comment: я, видимо, плохо объяснил. я мог бы показывать простой PictureBox. Но тогда он работал бы в том же основном треде, где в это же время (загрузка данных идёт) создаётся куча графических объектов. я попробовал этот способ - всё жутко тормозит. А если я запускаю браузер - то браузер то работает в своём процессе, и меня не беспокоит то, что в основном треде приложения создаётся куча графических объектов.

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: @aepot - Спасибо большое за предложение! я постараюсь сделать минимальный пример, воспросизводщий проблему, и опубликую его в отдельном вопросе.

Comment: Загрузку ресурсов тоже можно вынести в отдельный поток. В общем в следующий раз хотя-бы объясните, откуда костыли торчат, и какая именно задача решается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WebBrowser` (Internet Explorer 11) [не поддерживает](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) `display: flex` так как это делают нормальные свежие браузеры.

Я не рекомендую вам использовать этот браузер. Но если очень хочется, то есть `CefSharp` ([github](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp), доступен в NuGet) и `WebView2` ([документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms)), оба работают на одинаковом хромовском движке.

Если у вас тормозит `PictureBox`, попробуйте включить буферизацию для формы.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //включение двойной буферизации на уровне окна
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;    // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }

    // ....
}
```